# Share html android file

Tags: android

I want to share HTML being a file and not in text form. First, would I need to generate a saved file on the phone to send later?

```
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(meuHtml));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First save the file in .html format.

Then Select it from Gallery, get the file uri and create a Share Intent

Here is the complete Guide official doc link

[Sharing a File](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html)

Comment: `Then Select it from Gallery, ` ??? Selecting html files from Gallery? How would that go? And why would someone need to select it when the path is known already?

Comment: Either you can select from File Explorer, or you can use File Uri whichever is comfortable for you

Comment: I would not be able to generate this file when I send it without saving on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I use this to share my html files.

(This Might Not Work on phones with android 9+)

```
String filename = "YOURFILENAME.html";
    String filepath = "html";
    File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
        fos.write(YOURTEXT.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    try{
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/android/data/YOURPACKAGENAME (com.example.sharehtml)/files", "html");
        File gpxfile = new File(file, filename);
        Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if(gpxfile.exists()) {
            intentShareFile.setType("text/html");
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + gpxfile));
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Sharing HTML File...");
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, YOURTEXT);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share HTML File"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```